# Is it posible to have multi dimensional result set in sql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

can I have a 3 dimensional array result set in sql stored procedure

just asking if its posible.

something like this

```
[
    parent => [
        child_id => [
            associative[]
            ...
        ]
        ...
    ]

    someone => [
        id => associative[]
        ...
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes.  Just return three columns.

Comment: if you want a `3 dimensional` **array**, then I too recommend you the @GordonLinoff 's comment.

Comment: can it be associative?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a look at WITH CUBE.  [Here's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175939%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) a good place to start.